# Syntax Error in Spring-Boot by eccessing postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I wanted to Connect my Database to my Spring-Boot Application and got this error:

```
2022-08-15 14:09:33.401  INFO 39260 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2022-08-15 14:09:33.992  WARN 39260 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table user (id int8 not null, email varchar(
255), firstname varchar(255), lastname varchar(255), password varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table user (id int8 not null, email varchar(255), firstname varchar(255), lastname varchar(255), password varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDB
C Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at de.chris.appStarter.main(appStarter.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 14
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:329) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:315) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:286) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
2022-08-15 14:09:33.996  INFO 39260 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-08-15 14:09:34.004  INFO 39260 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-15 14:09:34.233  WARN 39260 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly confi
gure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-08-15 14:09:34.508  INFO 39260 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-08-15 14:09:34.517  INFO 39260 --- [           main] de.chris.appStarter                      : Started appStarter in 3.288 seconds (JVM running for 3.739)
2022-08-15 14:13:52.089  INFO 39260 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-15 14:13:52.090  INFO 39260 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-15 14:13:52.091  INFO 39260 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2022-08-15 14:13:52.229  WARN 39260 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2022-08-15 14:13:52.229 ERROR 39260 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 13
```

I got an Spring Application with database access before and everything worked fine, so I copied most of these things like application.properties:

```
spring.sql.init.platform = postgres
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/User_DB
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

or the Interface which extends out of CrudRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    public interface Users extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    }
```

even the class was similar:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: *Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"*. I would say that `user` is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL and you need to pick another table name for your `User` entity, maybe `users` would work? `@Table(name="users")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception says *Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"*.

That is happening because `user` is a reserved keyword. In this case, you can pick a different table name for your `User` entity. Try `@Table(name="users")`.